# Apply same data for two resources in loop terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-sns

I want to create two Amazon SNS topics with the same `aws_iam_policy_document`, `aws_sns_topic_policy` & `time_sleep` configs.

This is my terraform, `my_sns_topic.tf`:

```
resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic_a" {
  name = "topic-a"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic_b" {
  name = "topic-b"
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "topic_notification" {
  version = "2008-10-17"
  statement {
    sid = "__default_statement_ID"
    actions = [
      "SNS:Publish"
    ]

# Cut off some lines for simplification.
## NEW LINE ADDED
  statement {
    sid = "allow_snowflake_subscription"
    principals {
      type        = "AWS"
      identifiers = [var.storage_aws_iam_user_arn]
    }

    actions   = ["SNS:Subscribe"]
    resources = [aws_sns_topic.topic_a.arn] # Troubles with this line
  }
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "topic_policy_notification" {
  arn    = aws_sns_topic.topic_a.arn
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.topic_policy_notification.json
}

resource "time_sleep" "topic_wait_10s" {
  depends_on      = [aws_sns_topic.topic_a]
  create_duration = "10s"
}
```

As you can see here, I set up the configuration only for `topic-a`. I want to loop this over to apply for `topic-b` as well.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to use [map](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/map) and [for_each](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/for_each), instead of separately creating "a" and "b" topics:

```
variable "topics" {
    default = ["a", "b"]
}


resource "aws_sns_topic" "topic" {
  for_each = toset(var.topics)
  name     = "topic-${each.key}"
}


data "aws_iam_policy_document" "topic_notification" {
  version = "2008-10-17"
  statement {
    sid = "__default_statement_ID"
    actions = [
      "SNS:Publish"
    ]

# Cut off some lines for simplification.
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "topic_policy_notification" {
  for_each = toset(var.topics)
  arn      = aws_sns_topic.topic[each.key].arn
  policy   = data.aws_iam_policy_document.topic_policy_notification.json
}

resource "time_sleep" "topic_wait_10s" {
  for_each        = toset(var.topics)
  depends_on      = [aws_sns_topic.topic[each.key]]
  create_duration = "10s"
}
```

Comment: I have trouble in `data` block, I've updated the codes. Now I get this error `Error: Missing resource instance key. Because aws_sns_topic.topic has "for_each" set, its
│ attributes must be accessed on specific instances.
│ 
│ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
│     aws_sns_topic.topic[each.key] ```

Comment: But I can't add `for_each` in `data` block. How to fix this?

Comment: @user6185827 Data blocks were not part of your original question. This is a new issue, thus please make new question for that with relevant details.